# How to categorize images?

Tags: html, image

Hello there (I'm a web developer beginner here)
i want to categorize my images or to sort by selecting a  tag
i don't know how to show only pandas, bears, or dogs
(sorry for my english)

Example Code:

```html
<div align="center">
  <select>
        <option>Please Chosse</option>
        <option>Pandas</option>
        <option>Bears</option>
        <option>Dogs</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0f/Grosser_Panda.JPG/1200px-Grosser_Panda.JPG" width="200px" align="center"></td>
      <td><img src="https://unagb.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/grizzly-bear2.jpg" width="200px" align="center"></td>
      <td><img src="http://www.hillspet.com/HillsPetUS/v1/portal/en/us/dog-care/images/HP_PCC_md_0144_dog37.jpg" width="200px" align="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://cdn.history.com/sites/2/2017/03/GettyImages-157278376.jpg" width="200px" align="center"></td>
      <td><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/17/2a/d9/172ad9712f7decf28520a55796d3020a.jpg" width="200px" align="center"></td>
      <td><img src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/article_small/public/thumbnails/image/2017/06/08/18/rottweiler-dog.jpg" width="200px" align="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://www.adelaidezoo.com.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/animals/giant-panda1-706x456.jpg" width="200px" align="center"></td>
      <td><img src="https://puxccbo05z-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/grizzly-bear-1.jpg" width="200px" align="center"></td>
      <td><img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2017-04/25/4/enhanced/buzzfeed-prod-fastlane-01/enhanced-23831-1493109569-1.jpg" width="200px" align="center"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You may at least show us, what you already tried... Anyway. I would generally suggest not to use a <table> here, but only <div> with display:inline-block. Then I would add a class to every image and later use them to show or hide pictures.

Comment: You mean javascript, 

a trigger that hide picture in <div>
right?

Comment: Yes, or jquery. $('.dog').hide() would for examle hide all images with a class="dog" attribute

Comment: what you use? Javscript or jQuery?

Comment: well..... i don't know how both javascript and jQuery.....i think javascript is most common to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a class to each image this will help you to categorize
- Learn about jQuery or another library that can help you with this type of tasks

This example can help you im using jquery for this

```js
(function() {
  var $imgs = $('#gallery img');
  var $buttons = $('#buttons');
  var tagged = {};

  $imgs.each(function() {
    var img = this;
    var tags = $(this).data('tags');

    if (tags) {
      tags.split(',').forEach(function(tagName) {
        if (tagged[tagName] == null) {
          tagged[tagName] = [];
        }
        tagged[tagName].push(img);
      })
    }
  })

  $('<button/>', {
    text: 'Show All',
    class: 'active',
    click: function() {
      $(this)
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings()
        .removeClass('active');
      $imgs.show();
    }
  }).appendTo($buttons);

  $.each(tagged, function(tagName) {
    var $n = $(tagged[tagName]).length;
    $('<button/>', {
      text: tagName + '(' + $n + ')',
      click: function() {
        $(this)
          .addClass('active')
          .siblings()
          .removeClass('active');
        $imgs
          .hide()
          .filter(tagged[tagName])
          .show();
      }
    }).appendTo($buttons);
  });
}())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="buttons"></div>
  <div id="gallery">
    <img data-tags="Pandas"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0f/Grosser_Panda.JPG/1200px-Grosser_Panda.JPG" width="200px" align="center"></td>
      <img data-tags="Bears" src="https://unagb.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/grizzly-bear2.jpg" width="200px" align="center"></td>
      <img data-tags="Dogs" src="http://www.hillspet.com/HillsPetUS/v1/portal/en/us/dog-care/images/HP_PCC_md_0144_dog37.jpg" width="200px" align="center">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... I will try this